# OAuth2 with Okta jhispter documentation instructions

Tags: jhipster, okta

I use jhipster 5.4.1. simple monolithic app with OAuth2. I try with both angluar or React generation.

It works with Keycloak local test.

I follow all instructions from https://www.jhipster.tech/security/ for Okta.

And then, I have error 404 when jhispter app trying to access okta

https://dev-796955-admin.oktapreview.com/error/404?fromURI=%2Foauth2%2Fdefault%2Fv1%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%My okta client id is here%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520email%26state%some state

Are Instructions :

> specify http://localhost:8080 as a Base URI and
>   http://localhost:8080/login as a Login Redirect URI

in okta web app correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the “-admin” from your Okta URL and everything should work.